# styling of links applies to images?

Tags: html, css, menu

i'm having this really frustrating problem where a thin silver of the color that i'm applying as the a:hover,a:active is appearing outside of where it should. i have an image in absolute positioning right above the menu that is exhibiting this....i could just move the image up one but i want to solve it the correct way....here is my css

```
.logo
{
width:200px;
height:108px;
position:absolute;
left:5px;
top:10px;
}

#menu
{
position:relative;
top:110px;
padding-top:0px;
clear:both;
}

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0px;
width:900px;
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
}

li
{
float:left;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:3px;
width:120px;
height:auto;
color:#000000;
float:left;
}

a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#804000;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

here is my corresponding html:
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Sorry, your browser doesn’t support JavaScript!
    U4U Test Page

```
<div class="header">
<a href="/" class="imglink"><img class="logo" src="linktofilehere" alt="U4U Logo" /></a>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="/" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/About_Us.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/Initiatives.html">Programs</a></li>
<li><a href="/involvement.html">US Movement</a></li>
<li><a href="/Sponsorship.html">Sponsorship</a></li>
<li><a href="/donate.html">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i've searched through the help knowledge and couldn't find anything related really....i'm sure it is something simple....any help would be appreciate, i think it might have to do with positioning or not defining the hover area correctly but i'm not sure....i just started learning html and css last week so please be kind!

Comment: Can you create a reproducing jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you want it to not display any color when the image is hovered over?

Comment: Here's a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/aMJJ3/

Comment: sorry, new at this...here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6UfFb/

Comment: if you view the js fiddle, you can see the small brown sliver that is appearing above the image when it is not supposed to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a new style for the 'a' of your image. If you don't, it will use the standard 'a' stylings of your CSS.

Like this :

```
a.imglink:hover 
{
background:none;
}
```

Comment: hey! it looks like this is what everyone is saying is the best answer...thanks for contributing!

Comment: No problem! :) And good work with ul li menus, those can become quite tricky quite quick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a style to remove the background color from linked images - that way you won't run into issues with transparent PNGs etc:

`.imglink:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* remove the background */
.imglink:hover { background: none; }

/* if you run into specificity issues, be more selective! :) */
a.imglink:hover { background: none; }

/* or remove the padding from just the first a */
a:first-of-type{ padding: 0; }

/* or remove the background from the first link */
a:first-of-type{ background: none; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/aMJJ3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I just specifically targetted links inside the list for the background color on hover..

**CSS:**

```
#menu > ul > li > a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#804000;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSSU7/

Did this solve your problem?